# Why does splinter is_text_present() cause intermittent StaleElementReferenceException with Firefox (but not Chrome or phantomjs)?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, splinter

After upgrading my test environment to the latest versions of [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), [splinter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/splinter), and Firefox, one of my tests now fails about 80% of the time using Firefox with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rbednark/Dropbox/git/quizme_website/questions/tests.py", line 103, in test_login_fails_incorrect_username
    "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again."
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/quizme-django-1.6.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 302, in is_text_present
    self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text.index(text)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/quizme-django-1.6.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 73, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/quizme-django-1.6.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/quizme-django-1.6.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/quizme-django-1.6.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
```

Note that this same test passes 100% of the time using Chrome and phantomjs.  The test:

```
self.browser.visit(self.live_server_url)
self.assertEquals(self.browser.title, 'Quiz Me!')
self.browser.find_by_id('id_username')[0].fill(user)
self.browser.find_by_id('id_password')[0].fill(password)
# note that the following click() causes a page load
self.browser.find_by_value('login').click()
self.assertTrue(
      self.browser.is_text_present(
          "Your username and password didn't match. "
          "Please try again."
  )
)
```

firefox upgraded from `49.0.2` to `50.1.0`
selenium upgraded from `2.46.0` to `3.0.2`
splinter upgraded from `0.6.0` to `0.7.5`
geckodriver `0.13.0`
(the above are all the latest versions at the time this was posted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by implementing this wrapper that retries when the exception is caught:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

def _loop_is_text_present(text, max_attempts=3):
    attempt = 1
    while True:
        try:
            return self.browser.is_text_present(text)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            if attempt == max_attempts:
                raise
            attempt += 1
```

Inspired by: http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2012/06/staleelementexception.html

Selenium source code that [describes the StaleElementReferenceException.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1d05820edabd58c7e4b6afd04e5596404bd1cd7c/py/selenium/common/exceptions.py#L106-L121)